# Problems with txt-export under Macintosh

Tags: export

I exported data form Mathematica to txt-format on my Mac. When opening the txt-file on a Windows-System the file does not appear as on my Mac (see screenshots).

Code:
`Export["Example.txt", {{"Test1", 1, 2, 3, 4}, {"Test2", 5, 6, 7, 8}}]`

Mathematica Documentation Center says "`Export` uses the line separator convention of the computer system on which Mathematica is being run."

How can I generate a txt-file under Mac OS, so that this file can be read correctly under Windows to?

BTW: I would like to get rid of the braces, quotation marks and commas within the txt-file.

[image]
[image: Mac Screenshot with code]

Comment: Have you tried not using the default OS convention and setting an explicit separator?

Comment: You can also not use notepad and use an editor that will read the file properly like notepad++

Comment: or try `Export["Example.txt", Compress@{{"Test1", 1, 2, 3, 4}, {"Test2", 5, 6, 7, 8}}]` and then `Uncompress@Import[...]`

Comment: I suspect this is a `\n` vs. `\r\n` issue. To solve this and to get rid of the braces, commas and quotation marks you could try doing something like `Export["Example.txt", {{"Test1", 1, 2, 3, 4}, {"Test2", 5, 6, 7, 8}}, "Table", "LineSeparators" -> "\r\n"]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To eliminate the braces and quotes,  you can use the `OutputForm` of `TableForm` like this:

```
testtext = {{"Test1", 1, 2, 3, 4}, {"Test2", 5, 6, 7, 8}}

Export["text.txt", OutputForm[TableForm[testtext]]]
```

However, this puts a blank line in between rows.

Heike's suggestion in comments also works, and does not put a blank line between rows, but I would suggest adding a `CharacterEncoding` option if you are sure you will only use the result on a Windows machine.

```
Export["text.txt", testtext, "Table", 
 CharacterEncoding -> "WindowsANSI", "LineSeparators" -> "\r\n"]
```

Answer (score 5):

The reason for this is that Windows/DOS and Unix-based systems (like OS X) use different conventions for [encoding newlines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline).

Windows/DOS use a sequence of two character codes: `13` and `10` (`13` representing the cursor or print-head returning to the start of the line and `10` representing advancing to the next line).  Unix/OS X use a single code: `10`.  When you use Windows Notepad to open a text file created on a Mac, it will not display it correctly. The little boxes you see represent character code `10`, but Notepad never sees a full `13 10` sequence that it can interpret as a newline.

So the problem is not specific to Mathematica.  I would suggest that you use a different text editor than Notepad (for example [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/)), as today nearly all of them support both types of line endings.

---

Regarding exporting to a table-like format (with no braces), use the [`Table`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/Table.html) export format:

```
Export["Example.txt", {{"Test1", 1, 2, 3, 4}, {"Test2", 5, 6, 7, 8}}, "Table"]
```